# Avoiding { in tkinter label coming from tuple

Tags: python, tkinter, tuples, label

So I moved from printing my results to displaying them via a tkinter label.

ttk.Label(root, text = ('Erlaubte Fehlergrenze zwischen', hin1,' und ', hin2,' = ',fehlergrenze,' Wir haben: ', fehler)).pack()

Now I have the problem that I get unwanted brackets {} seemingly coming from ''.

Example for a current output: {Erlaubte Fehlergrenze zwischen} 0100042 { und } 0100047 { = } 2.83 { Wir haben: } 2.78

I am thinking the problem here is that I am trying to display a tuple instead of a string, so I decided to convert it into a string and display it which doesnt seem too smart either.

Maybe there is an easier/better option to just avoid those brackets?

Thanks in advance.

Example for a wanted output: Erlaubte Fehlergrenze zwischen 0100042  und  0100047  =  2.83  Wir haben:  2.78

Comment: The `text` argument is supposed to a `str`ing so there is nothing wrong with converting your data into a `str`ing before passing it in. Actually that is what `tkinter` expects you to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? Using f-strings in Python 3.6 and later.

Code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

hin1 = '0100042'
hin2 = '0100047'
fehlergrenze = 2.83  
fehler = 2.47
ttk.Label(root, text = f'Erlaubte Fehlergrenze zwischen {hin1 } und { hin2} = { fehlergrenze } Wir haben:{fehler}').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Output image:

[image]

Comment: You, too! Have a good one.